# A problem occurred evaluating project ':@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation-common'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, geolocation

I try to clone my teammate project, i did `yarn install` and `run android` but when the process is done, i found an error said:

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':@mauron85_react-native-background-geolocation-common'

Other explanation are:

Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.library']

1. The option 'android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources' is deprecated.
2. The current default is 'false'.
3. It has been removed from the current version of the Android Gradle plugin.
4. The raw resource for unit test functionality is removed.

We still want to use this dependecy because it requires on our project, my React Native version is 0.61.5

is there any solution regarding this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line in gradle.properties in android folder.

```
android.enableUnitTestBinaryResources=false
```